# Time Based Reminder Email in Django

Tags: django

I want incorporate a timed based reminder email of the events for the day in django. Basically I have a model which has all the events (including the date of the event). I want to send emails to concerned people at around 8.00 AM in the morning of each day about the events for the day. How do I incorporate this is django?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I reckon a custom management command to send the alerts, commanded by [django-chronograph](http://code.google.com/p/django-chronograph/) should do the trick

Comment: Yeah, it's really good - v handy with session cleanup, registration profile purging etc

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a database-backed email queue, to send out emails from a single django install and not have to worry about SMTP throttling and whatnot. It's dead simple -- one model class for the email with a `sendit()` method, and a command-line script to flush the queue, which I run with cron.

http://gist.github.com/629663